# Conversion from Mindmanager to MS-Project

Tags: ms-project, mind-manager

In general Mindmanager offers an MS Project import/export.
But only if you have MS-Project installed. Which is basically against any Logic, because import/export is there to exchange information.

I don't want to buy MS-P because I don't need it. It's just to exchange files.

Are there any solutions known to import/export MS-P files with MM.

Options:

- Just get the required files installed
- XSLT transformation

Any hint's/help appreciated.

Comment: What file formats can MindManager import? I'm wondering if you can use MPXJ to read the schedule data, and export a format which MindManager can read without having any other software installed.

Comment: MM can import and export MPX and ?.xml files. But they require MS-P to be installed, which is not an option. On the other hand the MM-files are .xml-files as well. So a tranlation should be a matter of XSLT only. Which wouold eliminate the need to install MS-P. At least what the little guy thinks. :-)  I have seen already some translators from freemind eg.

Comment: I can probably implement something suitable as part of MPXJ, but before I look at the MindManager xml format, I was curious to understand what other file types MindManager can import (for example, CSV) which might be easier to generate. Can you point me in the direction of some documentation which describes how MindManager transforms from the data from MS Project into a mind map?

Comment: @john on Import this are  
MS-Word and OPML  
on export  
CSV, Powerpoint, Word, OPML and some specific like HTML5-Map (the content as an HTML-Navaigaiontal Map.  
What I have found also is some links  
http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Import_and_export_to_other_applications#To_MS_Project or  
http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Import_and_export_to_other_applications#To_MindManager  
I'll try to identify the MM-Spec.

Comment: @john just an important note: the current version is MM 2017 but most of the datastructures from X5 should still be valid.